# Firebase Analytics app_remove not firing after a while?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I was able to log the first six executions of my app on debug mode using this function:

```
exports.appUninstall = functions.analytics.event('app_remove').onLog(event => {
    console.log('HEY IM WORKING');
    console.log(event);
}
```

But, even tho i changed nothing, the event isnt firing anymore, any ideas?

Comment: Hi Vinicius, Is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

For this trigger to work, you must mark the `app_remove` event as a conversion event in Firebase's Analytics dashboard